# Issue AppAuth iOS "invalid_grant: Bad Request"

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, appauth

I have used AppAuth iOS for access Google Drive, 10 days ago, everything worked fine, I could fetch files from my drive normally. But today, (I have not changed code for 10 days) I can not fetch files, it's having this issue:

> Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.oauth_token Code=-10 "invalid_grant: Bad Request" UserInfo={OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey={
>   error = "invalid_grant";
>   "error_description" = "Bad Request";
>   }, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d1cdb0 {Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.remote-http Code=400 "{
>   "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "Bad Request"
>   }" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription={
>   "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "Bad Request"
>   }}}, request=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x6000003cdbf0> { URL: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=kind%2C%20nextPageToken%2C%20files%28id%2C%20mimeType%2C%20kind%2C%20name%2C%20webViewLink%2C%20thumbnailLink%2C%20trashed%2C%20parents%2C%20fileExtension%2C%20modifiedTime%2C%20size%29&prettyPrint=false&q=%27root%27%20IN%20parents }, NSLocalizedDescription=invalid_grant: Bad Request}

Does anyone have any solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi @Minh Văn, it would be good to include a piece of the source code you're using to access google drive so others can help you find the issue.

Comment: I just forgot to assign auth state for GTLRDriveService.[solve]

Comment: Check the "Authorization scopes" if you are adding right scope.

Answer (score 0):

now google drive have change in there api's i also faced same issue i fixed like 
Now i am sending a header like this for getting the files

```
var dict = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
dict["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authClientAccessToken
```

it definitely work !!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**P/s:
this is my code to make request and authorizing**